# What is the difference between when binding data to tableview cell iOS by using didSet method or using a function in iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didset

> 1. we can bind data to the `UITableViewCell` like below in `didSet` method.

```
class NameCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        selectionStyle = .none
    }

    var name: String! {
        didSet {
            nameLabel.text = name
        }
    }
}
```

---

> 2. Or we can bind the data using a function like below.

```
class NameCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        selectionStyle = .none
    }

    func bindName(name: String) {
       nameLabel.text = name
    }
}
```

**What is the difference between these two approaches when it comes to performance and reliability of the app with large chunk of data**

Comment: @matt : https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/mat` , @Keshu R: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8374890/keshu-r, @TylerH: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756409/tylerh, I changed the title and this is not an option based question. I really don't understand this. that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

This varies from developer to developer. I prefer the first one if the code structures in `didset` is too small. But if you make some calculations and decisions then the second one is better to me. It actually depends on you, so there is no specific answer.